# An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll

Tags: c#, wcf, debugging, logging, soap

I am trying to debug/log SOAP messages for C# WCF Project, but I get:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll 
>    
>   Additional information: The type initializer for 'System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility' threw an exception.

My `app.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="True">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml"></add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>

  <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
    <listeners>
      <add name="xml"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>

  <source name="myUserTraceSource"
        switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing">
    <listeners>
      <add name="xml"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>

  <sharedListeners>
    <add name="xml"
         type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
               initializeData="C:\users\scott\Traces.svclog" />
  </sharedListeners>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>

      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="debug">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="endpointCredentialBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate findValue="attdev.drsllc.net"
                               x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"
                               storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                               storeName="TrustedPeople" />
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="CreateBillingDisputeSoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>

        <binding name="CreateBillingReportSoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>

        <binding name="EchoSoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" >
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"  />
          </security>
        </binding>

        <binding name="InquireBillingDisputeDetailsSoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>

        <binding name="InquireBillingInvoiceDetailsSoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>

        <binding name="InquireBillingInvoiceSummarySoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>

        <binding name="InquireEnterpriseOrderDetailsSoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>

        <binding name="InquireEnterpriseOrderListSoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" >
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"  />
          </security>
        </binding>

        <binding name="InquireEnterpriseOrderStatusSoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>

        <binding name="InquireNetworkProductCatalogSoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>

        <binding name="InquireNetworkProductPriceQuoteSoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>

        <binding name="InquireNetworkProductRateCardSoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>

        <binding name="InquireSLACreditClaimStatusSoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>

        <binding name="InquireSLANetworkCreditClaimStatusSoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>

        <binding name="InquireSalesAccountProfileSoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>

        <binding name="InquireUnifiedBillingReferenceDataSoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>

        <binding name="ManageCustomLabelSoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>

        <binding name="SendBillingReplyNotificationSoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>

        <binding name="SubmitCustomerInquirySoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>

        <binding name="SubmitSLACreditClaimSoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>

        <binding name="UpdateBillingDisputeSoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>

        <binding name="ValidateAddressServiceAvailabilitySoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>

      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/bdebill/CreateBillingDispute.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CreateBillingDisputeSoapHttpBinding"
          contract="CreateBillingDisputePortType" name="CreateBillingDisputeSoapHttpPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/bdebill/CreateBillingReport.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CreateBillingReportSoapHttpBinding"
          contract="CreateBillingReportPortType" name="CreateBillingReportSoapHttpPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/echo/Echo.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="EchoSoapHttpBinding"
          contract="EchoPortType" name="EchoSoapHttpPort" behaviorConfiguration="endpointCredentialBehavior" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/bdebill/InquireBillingDisputeDetails.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="InquireBillingDisputeDetailsSoapHttpBinding"
          contract="InquireBillingDisputeDetailsPortType" name="InquireBillingDisputeDetailsSoapHttpPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/bdebill/InquireBillingInvoiceDetails.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="InquireBillingInvoiceDetailsSoapHttpBinding"
          contract="InquireBillingInvoiceDetailsPortType" name="InquireBillingInvoiceDetailsSoapHttpPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/bdebill/InquireBillingInvoiceSummary.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="InquireBillingInvoiceSummarySoapHttpBinding"
          contract="InquireBillingInvoiceSummaryPortType" name="InquireBillingInvoiceSummarySoapHttpPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/iof/InquireEnterpriseOrderDetails.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="InquireEnterpriseOrderDetailsSoapHttpBinding"
          contract="InquireEnterpriseOrderDetailsPortType" name="InquireEnterpriseOrderDetailsSoapHttpPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/sxp/InquireEnterpriseOrderList.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="InquireEnterpriseOrderListSoapHttpBinding"
          contract="InquireEnterpriseOrderListPortType" name="InquireEnterpriseOrderListSoapHttpPort" behaviorConfiguration="endpointCredentialBehavior" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/sxp/InquireEnterpriseOrderStatus.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="InquireEnterpriseOrderStatusSoapHttpBinding"
          contract="InquireEnterpriseOrderStatusPortType" name="InquireEnterpriseOrderStatusSoapHttpPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/pricing/InquireNetworkProductCatalog.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="InquireNetworkProductCatalogSoapHttpBinding"
          contract="InquireNetworkProductCatalogPortType" name="InquireNetworkProductCatalogSoapHttpPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/pricing/InquireNetworkProductPriceQuote.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="InquireNetworkProductPriceQuoteSoapHttpBinding"
          contract="InquireNetworkProductPriceQuotePortType" name="InquireNetworkProductPriceQuoteSoapHttpPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/pricing/InquireNetworkProductRateCard.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="InquireNetworkProductRateCardSoapHttpBinding"
          contract="InquireNetworkProductRateCardPortType" name="InquireNetworkProductRateCardSoapHttpPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/isom/InquireSLACreditClaimStatus.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="InquireSLACreditClaimStatusSoapHttpBinding"
          contract="InquireSLACreditClaimStatusPortType" name="InquireSLACreditClaimStatusSoapHttpPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/isom/InquireSLANetworkCreditClaimStatus.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="InquireSLANetworkCreditClaimStatusSoapHttpBinding"
          contract="InquireSLANetworkCreditClaimStatusPortType" name="InquireSLANetworkCreditClaimStatusSoapHttpPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/bdebill/InquireSalesAccountProfile.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="InquireSalesAccountProfileSoapHttpBinding"
          contract="InquireSalesAccountProfilePortType" name="InquireSalesAccountProfileSoapHttpPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/bdebill/InquireUnifiedBillingReferenceData.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="InquireUnifiedBillingReferenceDataSoapHttpBinding"
          contract="InquireUnifiedBillingReferenceDataPortType" name="InquireUnifiedBillingReferenceDataSoapHttpPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/bdebill/ManageCustomLabel.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ManageCustomLabelSoapHttpBinding"
          contract="ManageCustomLabelPortType" name="ManageCustomLabelSoapHttpPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/bdebill/SendBillingReplyNotification.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SendBillingReplyNotificationSoapHttpBinding"
          contract="SendBillingReplyNotificationPortType" name="SendBillingReplyNotificationSoapHttpPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/bdebill/SubmitCustomerInquiry.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SubmitCustomerInquirySoapHttpBinding"
          contract="SubmitCustomerInquiryPortType" name="SubmitCustomerInquirySoapHttpPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/isom/SubmitSLACreditClaim.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SubmitSLACreditClaimSoapHttpBinding"
          contract="SubmitSLACreditClaimPortType" name="SubmitSLACreditClaimSoapHttpPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/bdebill/UpdateBillingDispute.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="UpdateBillingDisputeSoapHttpBinding"
          contract="UpdateBillingDisputePortType" name="UpdateBillingDisputeSoapHttpPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/pricing/ValidateAddressServiceAvailability.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ValidateAddressServiceAvailabilitySoapHttpBinding"
          contract="ValidateAddressServiceAvailabilityPortType" name="ValidateAddressServiceAvailabilitySoapHttpPort" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>

The entire stack trace:
System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233036
  Message=The type initializer for 'System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility' threw an exception.
  Source=System.ServiceModel
  TypeName=System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility
  StackTrace:
       at System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility.SetEtwProviderId()
       at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory..ctor()
       at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(Type channelType)
       at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(String endpointConfigurationName, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
       at System.ServiceModel.ConfigurationEndpointTrait`1.CreateSimplexFactory()
       at System.ServiceModel.ConfigurationEndpointTrait`1.CreateChannelFactory()
       at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannelFactoryRef(EndpointTrait`1 endpointTrait)
       at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.InitializeChannelFactoryRef()
       at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1..ctor(String endpointConfigurationName, String remoteAddress)
       at EchoPortTypeClient..ctor(String endpointConfigurationName, String remoteAddress) in c:\Clients\DRS\attws\attws\csi_v80_schema\CingularWirelessCSI.cs:line 22771
       at attws.Program.EchoTest() in c:\Clients\DRS\attws\attws\Program.cs:line 60
       at attws.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Clients\DRS\attws\attws\Program.cs:line 15
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
       HResult=-2146232062
       Message=Configuration system failed to initialize
       Source=System.Configuration
       BareMessage=Configuration system failed to initialize
       Line=0
       StackTrace:
            at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.PrepareConfigSystem()
            at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
            at System.Configuration.PrivilegedConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
            at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.GetConfigSection()
            at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.Initialize()
            at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.get_IndentSize()
            at System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.InitializeSettings()
            at System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.get_Listeners()
       InnerException: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
            HResult=-2146232062
            Message=Unrecognized configuration section source. (C:\Clients\DRS\attws\attws\bin\Debug\attws.vshost.exe.Config line 15)
            Source=System.Configuration
            BareMessage=Unrecognized configuration section source.
            Filename=C:\Clients\DRS\attws\attws\bin\Debug\attws.vshost.exe.Config
            Line=15
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)
                 at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
                 at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
                 at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
            InnerException:
```

Comment: what is the call stack?

Comment: {"Configuration system failed to initialize"}
Unrecognized configuration section source. (C:\Clients\DRS\attws\attws\bin\Debug\attws.vshost.exe.Config line 15)
Line 15 is: <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">

Answer (score 1):

Here is the corrected app.config....Things were in the wrong place.  I figured it out by drilling down into the inner exceptions/call stack and looking at the generated appname.exe.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml"></add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="myUserTraceSource"
            switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  <sharedListeners>
    <add name="xml"
         type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
               initializeData="C:\users\scott\Traces.svclog" />
  </sharedListeners>  
  </system.diagnostics>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>



  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="debug">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="endpointCredentialBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate findValue="attdev.drsllc.net" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="TrustedPeople" />
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="CreateBillingDisputeSoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="CreateBillingReportSoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="EchoSoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" >
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"  />

          </security>

        </binding>
        <binding name="InquireBillingDisputeDetailsSoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />

        </binding>
        <binding name="InquireBillingInvoiceDetailsSoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="InquireBillingInvoiceSummarySoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="InquireEnterpriseOrderDetailsSoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="InquireEnterpriseOrderListSoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" >
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"  />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="InquireEnterpriseOrderStatusSoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="InquireNetworkProductCatalogSoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="InquireNetworkProductPriceQuoteSoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="InquireNetworkProductRateCardSoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="InquireSLACreditClaimStatusSoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="InquireSLANetworkCreditClaimStatusSoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="InquireSalesAccountProfileSoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="InquireUnifiedBillingReferenceDataSoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="ManageCustomLabelSoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="SendBillingReplyNotificationSoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="SubmitCustomerInquirySoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="SubmitSLACreditClaimSoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="UpdateBillingDisputeSoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="ValidateAddressServiceAvailabilitySoapHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/bdebill/CreateBillingDispute.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CreateBillingDisputeSoapHttpBinding"
          contract="CreateBillingDisputePortType" name="CreateBillingDisputeSoapHttpPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/bdebill/CreateBillingReport.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CreateBillingReportSoapHttpBinding"
          contract="CreateBillingReportPortType" name="CreateBillingReportSoapHttpPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/echo/Echo.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="EchoSoapHttpBinding"
          contract="EchoPortType" name="EchoSoapHttpPort" behaviorConfiguration="endpointCredentialBehavior" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/bdebill/InquireBillingDisputeDetails.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="InquireBillingDisputeDetailsSoapHttpBinding"
          contract="InquireBillingDisputeDetailsPortType" name="InquireBillingDisputeDetailsSoapHttpPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/bdebill/InquireBillingInvoiceDetails.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="InquireBillingInvoiceDetailsSoapHttpBinding"
          contract="InquireBillingInvoiceDetailsPortType" name="InquireBillingInvoiceDetailsSoapHttpPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/bdebill/InquireBillingInvoiceSummary.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="InquireBillingInvoiceSummarySoapHttpBinding"
          contract="InquireBillingInvoiceSummaryPortType" name="InquireBillingInvoiceSummarySoapHttpPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/iof/InquireEnterpriseOrderDetails.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="InquireEnterpriseOrderDetailsSoapHttpBinding"
          contract="InquireEnterpriseOrderDetailsPortType" name="InquireEnterpriseOrderDetailsSoapHttpPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/sxp/InquireEnterpriseOrderList.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="InquireEnterpriseOrderListSoapHttpBinding"
          contract="InquireEnterpriseOrderListPortType" name="InquireEnterpriseOrderListSoapHttpPort" behaviorConfiguration="endpointCredentialBehavior" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/sxp/InquireEnterpriseOrderStatus.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="InquireEnterpriseOrderStatusSoapHttpBinding"
          contract="InquireEnterpriseOrderStatusPortType" name="InquireEnterpriseOrderStatusSoapHttpPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/pricing/InquireNetworkProductCatalog.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="InquireNetworkProductCatalogSoapHttpBinding"
          contract="InquireNetworkProductCatalogPortType" name="InquireNetworkProductCatalogSoapHttpPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/pricing/InquireNetworkProductPriceQuote.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="InquireNetworkProductPriceQuoteSoapHttpBinding"
          contract="InquireNetworkProductPriceQuotePortType" name="InquireNetworkProductPriceQuoteSoapHttpPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/pricing/InquireNetworkProductRateCard.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="InquireNetworkProductRateCardSoapHttpBinding"
          contract="InquireNetworkProductRateCardPortType" name="InquireNetworkProductRateCardSoapHttpPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/isom/InquireSLACreditClaimStatus.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="InquireSLACreditClaimStatusSoapHttpBinding"
          contract="InquireSLACreditClaimStatusPortType" name="InquireSLACreditClaimStatusSoapHttpPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/isom/InquireSLANetworkCreditClaimStatus.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="InquireSLANetworkCreditClaimStatusSoapHttpBinding"
          contract="InquireSLANetworkCreditClaimStatusPortType" name="InquireSLANetworkCreditClaimStatusSoapHttpPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/bdebill/InquireSalesAccountProfile.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="InquireSalesAccountProfileSoapHttpBinding"
          contract="InquireSalesAccountProfilePortType" name="InquireSalesAccountProfileSoapHttpPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/bdebill/InquireUnifiedBillingReferenceData.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="InquireUnifiedBillingReferenceDataSoapHttpBinding"
          contract="InquireUnifiedBillingReferenceDataPortType" name="InquireUnifiedBillingReferenceDataSoapHttpPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/bdebill/ManageCustomLabel.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ManageCustomLabelSoapHttpBinding"
          contract="ManageCustomLabelPortType" name="ManageCustomLabelSoapHttpPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/bdebill/SendBillingReplyNotification.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SendBillingReplyNotificationSoapHttpBinding"
          contract="SendBillingReplyNotificationPortType" name="SendBillingReplyNotificationSoapHttpPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/bdebill/SubmitCustomerInquiry.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SubmitCustomerInquirySoapHttpBinding"
          contract="SubmitCustomerInquiryPortType" name="SubmitCustomerInquirySoapHttpPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/isom/SubmitSLACreditClaim.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SubmitSLACreditClaimSoapHttpBinding"
          contract="SubmitSLACreditClaimPortType" name="SubmitSLACreditClaimSoapHttpPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/bdebill/UpdateBillingDispute.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="UpdateBillingDisputeSoapHttpBinding"
          contract="UpdateBillingDisputePortType" name="UpdateBillingDisputeSoapHttpPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://qa9-csiwwwi-tn.edc.cingular.net:19443/Services/com/cingular/csi/pricing/ValidateAddressServiceAvailability.jws"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ValidateAddressServiceAvailabilitySoapHttpBinding"
          contract="ValidateAddressServiceAvailabilityPortType" name="ValidateAddressServiceAvailabilitySoapHttpPort" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Started with line 18, the two source elements should be under sources in the system.diagnostics block, as it is to specify the trace sources that initiate tracing messages. Please read the MSDN article  *[Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229451%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)* for details.

Also, you can use the tool *WCF Service Configuration Editor* to edit your configuration file, which will verify it before save. The tool is under the *Tools* menu in Visual Studio.